# Calling C external library (.so) from android java

Tags: android-ndk, java-native-interface

I am writing an example android app to demonstrate the use of our (*university research*) C/C++ library.

I know that, using jni, we can call C functions from java.
However, I have not found a step by step set of instructions for how to do this within Android Studio Artic Fox.

I have seen the need to write jni compatible C wrapper functions, but have not found how to do this (*correctly formed function signatures*) or where to put them.

In addition, what do I need to change in the project setup to correctly build the project (*using gradle*) ?

Note that I have to use directly the pre-built .so file and the public header file which defines the set of public C functions for the library.

There are plenty of examples which give partial outdated information, but still nothing comprehensive - or have I missed something ?

Comment: The answer will depend largely on what said library does. Is it an image processing library? Networking? Audio? Please amend your question with an idea of how exactly you want to showcase the functionality.

Comment: No, it is a text to speech library, so no interaction with the UI.

Comment: Okay, so start with a Thread that simply calls a `native static` function in a loop. Write some JNI code for said `native` function that calls into your library.

Comment: That's the whole point of this question : how to write that jni code - function signatures, correct adjustment of the gradle build, where to put the jni code files (.c and .h I presume), etc

Comment: There is tons of documentation on how to get started on the Android developer site. And I don't know why you need to know the details of gradle build, just create a new JNI project and work from there? I can do File -> New and select Native C++, which is the new "fully native" Activity. Alternatively,  I can create a regular Android application, right click the app and say "Add C++ to module" to generate the necessary CMake stuff for me.

Comment: I am needing neither a fully native activity, nor an embedded cmake project. As stipulated above, I need to interface with an existing .so library and it is here where I am confused as to how to do this

Comment: The point of the embedded CMake project is to build the JNI wrapper code. At the very least you need a single  Java `native` method with an implementation in the JNI wrapper code that calls into your library. As for your own library, you can choose to ship it premade under the `jnilibs` directory, or you can choose to create an [IMPORTED target in CMake](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/configure-cmake#add-other-library) to simplify bringing your prebuilt library along.

Answer (score 3):

I put together a quick guide below, but I want to clarify how it all fits together first.
In an Android application, you can bind `native` methods to specially-named functions that are loaded from a native library.
These specially-named functions receive pointers to a JNIEnv struct to interact with the embedding Java application.

The native library is typically built using CMake. Any external dependencies (such as your prebuilt library) need to be made visible to CMake in its CMakeLists.txt. The weapon of choice here are IMPORTED libraries, which are exactly what you think they are.

### the steps

First, create an Android project with Kotlin as language.
Right click the app at the top of the tree and select "Add C++ to module" to generate the necessary build stuff.

Change your MainActivity.kt file to be:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    external fun doit();
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val nativeThread = Thread {
            doit()
        }
        nativeThread.start()
    }
}
```

You will get a build error stating "cannot resolve corresponding JNI function". If you select the quick fix for that, Android Studio will generate a .cpp file with the appropriate JNI wrapper code inside it.

The generated function will look like:

```
extern "C"
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_com_example_myapplication_MainActivity_doit(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz) {
    // TODO: implement doit()
}
```

and above that will be instructions on how to load the native library from Kotlin. Copy that code to your MainActivity.kt.

Edit that .cpp file to do whatever you need to do with your native library (eg #include some files and call some functions).

Finally, edit `app/src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt` to [point to your headers and precompiled library](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/configure-cmake#add-other-library).

Comment: Thank you for this example. I am working in Java, but I presume that the steps are roughly the same.  So I will give it a go :-)

Comment: After having written all this, I realized that is what the "Native C++" template already does for you..

Comment: Ok, still struggling !  Where do I find this "Native C++" template? It is not available in my list of "new file" types

Comment: It's one of the options under file -> new -> new project.